# How to fix configuration (or `suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck` but don't say I didn't warn you!)?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

This version (1.0.1) of the Compose Compiler requires Kotlin version 1.5.21 but you appear to be using Kotlin version 1.6.0 which is not known to be compatible.  **Please fix your configuration (or `suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck` but don't say I didn't warn you!).**

I just create a sample compose project & updated all suggested plugin, I got below issue, How to fix below issue?

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project D:\materialize compose\Materialize-Compose


> Configure project :app
ComposeOptions.kotlinCompilerVersion is deprecated. Compose now uses the kotlin compiler defined in your buildscript.

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugManifestForPackage UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE

> Task :app:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
w: ATTENTION!
This build uses unsafe internal compiler arguments:

-XXLanguage:+NonParenthesizedAnnotationsOnFunctionalTypes

This mode is not recommended for production use,
as no stability/compatibility guarantees are given on
compiler or generated code. Use it at your own risk!

e: This version (1.0.1) of the Compose Compiler requires Kotlin version 1.5.21 but you appear to be using Kotlin version 1.6.0 which is not known to be compatible.  Please fix your configuration (or `suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck` but don't say I didn't warn you!).

> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compressDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeLibDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:writeDebugAppMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions UP-TO-DATE

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 353ms
23 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 22 up-to-date
```

**Gradle:**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**App level Gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.materialize.compose"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        useIR = true
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.0.1'
        kotlinCompilerVersion '1.5.21'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.0.5"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:1.0.5"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:1.0.5"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.0.5"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.0.5"
}
```

Comment: The error is clear. You're using `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.0` which applied kotlin version `1.6.0` to all kotlin plugins. update the version to `1.5.21`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Kotlin 1.6.0, use the following top level build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.1.0-beta04'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
        kotlinOptions {
            freeCompilerArgs += [
                    "-Xuse-experimental=kotlin.ExperimentalUnsignedTypes",
                    "-Xuse-experimental=kotlinx.coroutines.DelicateCoroutinesApi",
                    "-Xuse-experimental=kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi",
                    "-Xuse-experimental=kotlinx.coroutines.FlowPreview",
                    "-Xuse-experimental=kotlinx.coroutines.InternalCoroutinesApi",
                    "-Xuse-experimental=kotlinx.serialization.ExperimentalSerializationApi",
                    "-Xuse-experimental=androidx.compose.animation.ExperimentalAnimationApi",
                    "-Xuse-experimental=androidx.compose.ExperimentalComposeApi",
                    "-Xuse-experimental=androidx.compose.material.ExperimentalMaterialApi",
                    "-Xuse-experimental=androidx.compose.runtime.ExperimentalComposeApi",
                    "-Xuse-experimental=androidx.compose.ui.ExperimentalComposeUiApi",
                    "-Xuse-experimental=coil.annotation.ExperimentalCoilApi",
                    "-Xuse-experimental=com.google.accompanist.pager.ExperimentalPagerApi",

            ]
        }
    }
}
```

For your app's buid.gradle, you should use settings like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

apply from: 'codeinc.gradle'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mydomain.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionName "1.0"

        versionCode 1
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11'
        useIR = true
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
        kotlinCompilerVersion '1.6.0'
    }
}

dependencies {

    def activity_version = '1.4.0'


    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0-alpha01'
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:$activity_version"
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-compose:$activity_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:$compose_version"

}
```